# Conditional WHERE in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, t-sql, linq-to-entities

Hi any suggestions on building a LINQ statement based on search criteria?

I'll be passing in an instance of a 'SearchCriteria' class with all parameters nullable.

I then want to

```
if (sc.a != null)
    // add to where

if (sc.b != null)
    // add to where
```

The key thing is these are to be ORs not ANDs.

Any tips?

And for bonus points I'd like to use 'contains' on an int? but I can only get equals or not equals.

Comment: "or" is tricky to combine; to do properly that involves expression trees and often a visitor/rewriter. How many variables do you have? Just the two? If so, frankly doing it exhaustively (i.e. 3 different regular lines - one X, one Y, one X || Y)

Comment: What ORM? LINQ to SQL or Entities Framework?

Comment: it will be potentially a dozen parameters.. and I am using EF....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
.Where(x =>
    (x.a != null ? x.a == a : false) &&
    (x.b != null ? x.b == b : false));
```

or

```
.Where(x =>
    (x.a != null && x.a == a) ||
    (x.b != null && x.b == b));
```

---

Also:

```
.Where(x => new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Contains(x.i));
```

Comment: This seems to be a clean and elegant solution... I'll see how well it scales. Re the second part. What I have is an int OrderID of 12345 I want to be able to search for 123 and find 123* with strings you can do.Contains but you can't with ints? Can this be made to work?

Comment: @JonH: Do you want yo use RegEx or Wildcard? There are multiple ways to achieve that. I suggest to search over SO or ask a new question, it's pretty complex.